# Unable to use loop as below requirement for each customer record

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a requirement that for each customer 1,2,3 , if address is present then only it should be included under XML.
Suppose for customer 1 there is AddressType both B and D and for Customer 2 there is AddressType only B, C.

Expected output is:

```
<xml version CIF  1
Mailing Address for Customer  is B
Home Address for Customer is D

<xml version CIF  2
Mailing Address for Customer  is B

#For Customer3 again there was both AddressType present so it should be as follows
<xml version CIF  3
Mailing Address for Customer  is B
Home Address for Customer is D
```

Python program that I have written is as below:

```
#Initialinzing the variables to blank
MailingAddress=''
PermanentAddress=''
Customer = ["1", "2", "3"]
for x in Customer:
  Customer=x[0]
  #print(Customer)
  #time.sleep(6)
  ADDRESS=["B","C","D"]
  XML=f'<xml version CIF  {str(Customer)}\n'
  for y in ADDRESS:
    AddrData=y[0]
    #print(ADDRESS)
    #MailingAddress=''
    if AddrData =="B":
        MailingAddress=f'Mailing Address for Customer  is {(AddrData)}\n'
    #PermanentAddress=''
    if AddrData =="D":
        #print(ADDRESS)
        PermanentAddress=f'Home Address for Customer is {(AddrData)}\n'

    ADDRESS=["B","C"]  # For suppose next record doesn't have PermanentAddress 
                       # so hardcoded changes maked.
    #print(MailingAddress,PermanentAddress)
  XML+= MailingAddress+PermanentAddress
  print(XML)
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignments `Customer=x[0]` and `AddrData=y[0]` are unnecessary since x and y variables will already have the next values in loop for Customer and ADDRESS arrays.
A better version can be as follows:

```
#Initialinzing the variables to blank
MailingAddress=''
PermanentAddress=''
Customer = ["1", "2", "3"]
ADDRESS=["B","C","D"]
for x in Customer:
    XML=f'<xml version CIF  {str(x[0])}\n'
    for y in ADDRESS:
        MailingAddress=''
        PermanentAddress=''
        if y =="B":
            MailingAddress=f'Mailing Address for Customer  is {(y)}\n'
        if y =="D":
            PermanentAddress=f'Home Address for Customer is {(y)}\n'
        XML+= MailingAddress+PermanentAddress
    print(XML)
    ADDRESS=["B","C"]  # Do the necessary changes to the ADDRESS variable for the next iteration.
```